# Log out and clear VCs below current VC

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

We are looking to change the way a user logs out of our app. In order to do that, we want to dismiss all the VCs below the current VC and put another VC on top as the root VC. Right now we are doing this which I believe does not dismiss any VC below from memory.

```
let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignIn")
if let unwrappedViewController = viewController {
     self.present(unwrappedViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
}
```

The problem is that the VC that we want to put on top is not embedded in a Navigation Controller or tab bar controller. How would we dismiss the VCs and set the new VC as the main VC as if the user was opening the app for the first time without having previously logged in? We also do want the transition to be animated with whatever animation is normal for that event (modal animation is fine). I have read a bunch of different ways on doing it but I want to know which way is best practice and should be implemented specifically dismissing all VCs and putting a new VC that isn't in a Nav controller on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access the `UIWindow` of the app, you can set its `rootViewController` property to your sign-in view controller, effectively removing all current view controllers and adding the sign-in view controller instead. Here's an example:

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

// Should remove all subsequent view controllers from memory.
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

// Set the root view controller to a new instance of the sign in view controller.
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignIn")
```

Comment: The problem is that our root view controller isn't a Nav controller so we cannot use these statements. Our root view controller is a standalone VC which is essentially our loading screen as the user is being authenticated with our backend to make sure that they have a valid user token. Essentially it is failing on the second line of code above.

Comment: Is your root view controller then presenting the following screens? If so you can do `appDelegate.window?.rootViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: is this a good way to do it? `guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { print ("error 1"); return }`

`let signInVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignIn")` `self.present(signInVC, animated: true, completion: { appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = signInVC })`

Comment: In this case we are just presenting a new VC and then once it is presented, we are setting it as the root view controller. Does this remove all the other view controllers that we previously loaded from memory? How do we check which VCs are still in memory? Is there a function that we can use to check that? Also when you set the root view controller, does that remove all the other view controllers from memory?

Comment: I updated my answer, hope that helps. And that is not a good way because you're presenting a new instance of sign-in on top of the old one (the old one will never be removed). Simply do a `dismiss` then set `rootViewController` and it should work.

Comment: Perfect. That did it but it removes the animation. I just animated the view using this `UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromBottom, animations: {
                appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignIn")
            }, completion: { completed in
                // maybe do something here
            })`